# Is gamma correction applied in my setup

Tags: conversion, camera, analog

I am working on a scientific application where I would like to evaluate luminance in an image, however I am unsure if what I receive from my setup is [luminance (Y)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance) or [luma (Y')](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_%28video%29). I use a camera with a [TOSH IK CU51 (PAL)](http://www.toshiba.ch/ics/media/pdfs/Brochures/Micro_Camera_1CCD/IK-CU51-Brochure.pdf) control unit which is connected via S-Video to a [Canopus ADVC-300](http://www.lib.neu.edu/dmdsiguide/Resources/Manuals/CANOPUSADVC300.pdf) analog to digital converter. The digitized data are streamed to a computer and presented in YUV2 format.

Now the problem: I read into luminance and luma and realized that I do not know if gamma compression is applied somewhere on the way between the camera and the computer, so that really I am getting Y'UV2 instead of YUV2, is there e.g. a definition for a PAL signal to be gamma compressed and for an S-Video signal not to be corrected?

Edit: As there are no answers yet, I think I should be more specific: Is there any flexibility in the PAL or S-Video standard or in how a device is generally expected to work where I would have to take gamma correction into account? 
A little more background: luminance is proportional to energy per spatial area. If gamma correction were applied then I'd get a somewhat distorted value. If I knew gamma, I could adjust for this.

Comment: Thanks, @ObscureRobot! I flagged the question and asked for moving it to dsp.SE

Answer (score 2):

You should photograph a known calibration target with your system, (like [this](http://www.image-engineering.de/images/downloads/manuals/testcharts/BBC64%20A%20datasheet.pdf) one or the one that I put in the thumbnail).

[image]

This will allow you discovering the [OECF](http://www.imatest.com/guides/modules/stepchart/) of your system. You can either calculate it by yourself, given the technical data sheet or use third-party software like [Imatest](http://www.imatest.com/), ImageAnalyzer or others.

Comment: @Sebastian, consider accepting the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: I hope to get an answer that involves definitions and specifications. Your answer is helping a lot, but it isabout testing an actual setup. Sorry, if I was not really clear about it.

Comment: @Sebastian, ok, you are right.